# Магазин на 100+ товаров на UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Доброго времени суток, у меня появилась задача сделать внутриигровой магазин на Юнити новым UI. Проблема заключаеться в том что в каждный товар имеет 3 вида панелек,

1. Товар куплен
2. Товар закрыт
3. Товар можно купить, там пишет цена.

Также перед тем как купить товар появляеться панелька где пишет: "Вы уверены что хотите купить товар?" "Цена товара" "Его иконка". такэже кнопка купить и вернуться назад.
И да, мне нужно при выходе сохранять все дело, чтоб человек если купил товар, он появился в "комнате" и когда он вышел с игры и назад зашел, оно все згрузилось и показало то товар куплен и он есть в "комнате", ну тут я думал все делать через PlayerPreffs но блин очень много пременных.

Немного на счет того что товар закрыт, у нас идет валидация где проверяеться лвл игрока и кажет товар открыт или закрыт.

Проблема в том что я не знаю как мне все кастомизировать и сделать все. Ладно товар на 10 едениц, тогда еще норм там банально можно через SetActive все сделать. А тут я не знаю(

Вобшем очень прошу вашей помощи, хоть натолкните на мыслю ибо я не знаю кк лучше сделать(, а те костыли что я написал я даже показывать не хочу(

Comment: Класс товара: содержит картинки для состояний, цену, статус (открыт/закрыт) и статус наличия (куплен/не куплен). При загрузке магазина - вызываем конструктор товара, куда передаём его данные + данные пользователя (уровень, характеристики). Конструктор формирует отображение товара на прилавке (открытый, закрытый и т.д.). Ну и методы "открыть/закрыть", "купить" и т.д. Концептуально всё через класс решается. Можно ещё слушатели в классе поставить для объекта игрока - если меняются свойства у игрока - меняются свойства товара - становится "открытым" например.